# Unable to connect to Deck via tunneling

Tags: ssh-tunnel, spinnaker, azure-aks, spinnaker-halyard

I installed the Halyard docker image on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM, created a Kubernetes Cluster in Azure AKS and deployed Spinnaker to it using `hal deploy apply`.

Everything looks good and I can see the pods running via Kubernetes dashboard (by tunneling in the VM.)
`az aks browse --resource-group SPIN --name AKS`

However, I am unable to connect to the spinnaker UI at `http://localhost:9000` via tunneling. This is what I did.

1. In my Ubuntu VM, started the Halyard container.

   ```
   sudo docker run -p 8084:8084 -p 9000:9000 --name halyard --rm -v \
   ~/.hal:/home/spinnaker/.hal -v ~/.kube:/home/spinnaker/.kube -d  \
   gcr.io/spinnaker-marketplace/halyard:stable
   ```
2. Connected to the container.

   ```
   jaise@halyard:~$ sudo docker exec -it halyard bash
   ```
3. Configured Spinnaker and deployed to AKS `hal deploy apply`
4. Ran `hal deploy connect`- which seems to verify everything and start a tunnel

   ```
   spinnaker@6e1e72124794:/workdir$ hal deploy connect
   + Get current deployment
     Success
   + Connect to Spinnaker deployment.
     Success
   Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9000 -> 9000
   Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8084 -> 8084
   ```
5. I opened my browser in VM and hit `http://localhost:9000` but nothing comes. The message displayed is " The connection was reset"
6. I Repeated the same steps from the putty session on my local workstation and received a similar error.

[image: Local Computer, Windows 8, Chrome]

Any hint on where to look and what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the AKS configuration for tunneling would need some tweaking to work with Halyard. The most supported path here is for GCP and I suspect the command won't work with AKS or Amazon EKS.

The documentation suggests you try the other alternative paths, such as exposing your node publicly after adding authentication https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/quickstart/faq/#i-want-to-expose-the-distributed-kubernetes-hosted-spinnaker-publicly .

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to configure authentication for Spinnaker but miserably failed. Anyway, I will be scrapping the current setup and will redo everything from scratch. Will keep this post updated.